# jQuery - how to make single html page with multiple slides - and only one should be visible at a time

Tags: jquery, html

I'm developing HTML5 application for a tablet. Idea is as follows: app consists of 5 articles, each article has 10 or so slides. Each slide fits perfectly to the screen, and there are left/right buttons to move to the next or previous slide. Also slides might have some jQuery animation, timers set, etc. There is also top-level menu where all articles are listed and user can navigate to them.

So, right now I have 5 html files, each file has 10 DIVs in it, and I have some logic to hide/display divs based on user actions. The requirement is to merge all 5 files into 1 single HTML file. Reason - to make transitions between articles smooth (right now screen blinks - because another HTML file is loaded).

I understand I can go with the  same approach as I have now with all these 50 divs - but there will be a lot of code, and it will hard to understand. I'm thinking about making some kind of state machine for transitions between articles/slides:

```
function changeSlide(bool forward)
{
    disableAnimationForAllSlides();

    var articleNumber = getArticle();
    var currentSlideNumber = getCurrentSlide();

    if (currentSlideNumber == 1 && forward == false)
    {
        goToArticleList();
        return;
    } else if (currentSlideNumber == 10 && forward == true)
    {
        goToArticleList();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        hideAllSlides();
        displaySlide(articleNumber, currentSlideNumber + 1);
        enableAnimationForSlide(articleNumber, currentSlideNumber + 1);
    }
}

function changeArticle(newArticleNumber)
{
    disableAnimationForAllSlides();
    hideAllSlides();

    displaySlide(newArticleNumber, 1);
    enableAnimationForSlide(newArticleNumber, 1);
}
```

and I think it's all relatively straightforward - but I do not want to reinvent the wheel... And of course my case is quite more complicated than this example. **So my questions are**:

1. What are the standard approaches for this task - having multiple slides in one HTML file with  transitions between them? How should I define next/prev elements for example, etc?
2. Is there any libraries/frameworks I can use for this?
3. Is there any example in the internet I can look at?

it's HTML5/CSS3/jQuery project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out [Deck.js](http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/)

It's a pretty full featured slide deck built using HTML5 and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a lovely example](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#landing-slide). It's an HTML5 website, built as a slidedeck and showing a lot of new and shiny stuff of HTML5. It features transitions between slides, support for arrow keys and even different styles (press T to switch themes).